# ADFS authtoken stay part of query string

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, adfs

We are using ADFS to authenticate SharePoint 2016 website. Once authenticated '`authToken`' stay part of the query string as follow. This is only happening first authenticated page. If I click on another page the '`authToken`' query string disappeared.

```
https://www.example.com/page.aspx?authToken=ADFSToken
```

If I used that URL in a different browser or someone else computer, user will be logged in directly.

Does anyone know how to remove 'authToken' from authenticated SharePoint page?

Comment: Did you try to use IIS URL rewriting to remove the query string?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IIS URL rewriting for hiding the parameter.

e.g.

```
  <rule name="Remove paging parameters" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)?$" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="authtoken=(*.)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

IIS Rewrite would remove authtoken and redirect to the original requested host.

Based on the idea of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234604/iis-rewrite-to-remove-certain-querystring-parameters-and-redirect-to-the-origina